# List<string> won't add XML-generated values when their valid

Tags: list, c#-4.0, nullreferenceexception

My program errors out with a Null Reference Exception when it attempts to add to a List

Code for the for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < UserCourses.Length; i++)
                        {
                            CurrentUser.Course_ID.Add(UserCourses[i]);
                        }
```

Code for CurrentUser (which is a new of type User)

```
public class User
        {
            public int coursenum;
            public string Username;
            public string Password;
            public string FirstName;
            public string LastName;
            public string Email_Address;
            public string User_Type;
            public List<string> Course_ID;
            public List<Course> Course;
        }
```

I had it display the UserCourses[i] and it displayed successfully with the correct information, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not initializing the `Course_ID` property to contain a reference to a new `List<string>`.  So you are calling `Add` on a null reference.

(Also, you might consider using the `AddRange` method, which will add the whole array/list you are attempting to add with one line of code.  This will eliminate the need to write your own loop.)

Comment: ie. somewhere in the class (usually class constructor) call "Course_ID = new List<string>();"